# Validating value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to validate a float that can be between 1 and 6.5 but only increments of .5 so {1, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5}. Is there any way to validate this in rails. So far I have:

```
validates :value, :inclusion => 1..6.5, is_value_valid => true

def is_value_valid
  if self.value % 0.5 == 0
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

I am getting errors when I am testing, I do not think this is how you call the `is_value_valid` method.

Comment: Multiply it by 2 and ask if it's an integer between 1 and 13?  Floating point ranges are ugly.

Comment: @MarcTalbot I think that's a great approach. Why not propose it as an answer?

Comment: It seemed to frivolous to be an answer, but I'll give it a try.  :)

Comment: @trev9065 : your method would work if you call it as a separate validation as in rafaelkin's answer (assuming you don't hit weird floating point issues).

Comment: You can do this to call a method for validation: `validates_inclusion_of :value, :if => lambda{ |n| (1..12) === n * 2 }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can validate it with a custom method, so your complete validation should look like this:

```
validates :value, :inclusion => {:in => 1..6.5}
validate :value_is_multiple_of_point_five

def value_is_multiple_of_point_five
    unless value % 0.5 == 0
        errors.add(:value, "must be multiple of 0.5")
    end
end
```

Comment: @rafarlkin When I am running my tests I am getting `validates': You need to supply at least one validation (ArgumentError)` with this solution.

Comment: Corrected. Thought that your first attempt was correct at least for inclusion :)

Comment: You can get more help on rails guides too http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're going to have to use a `t.decimal` column if you really need to have values like `1` and `5.5`, using a floating point value open the door to all the usual floating point problems. If you use a decimal column, Rails will be working with BigDecimal values for your `value` and you'll be okay as long as you keep everything in the land of BigDecimal:

```
validate :valid_value_very_vigorously
HALF  = BigDecimal('0.5')
UPPER = BigDecimal('6.5')
LOWER = BigDecimal('1.0')

def valid_value_very_vigorously
    errors.add(:value, "Value must be at least #{LOWER}") if(value < LOWER)
    errors.add(:value, "Value must be at most #{UPPER}")  if(value > UPPER)
    errors.add(:value, "Value must be a multiple of 0.5") if(value % HALF != 0)
end
```